# sendmessage in outlook C# addin not working

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to get an Outlook C# add-in to scroll the left navigation pane using SendMessage.  It seems to have no effect.  Does an add-in run under a lower privilege level than Outlook, therefore preventing SendMessage from working thanks to UIPI?

I iterate using EnumChildWindows (which is recursive) to find the left Navigation Pane child window's handle, as identified using Spy++, using GetWindowText to find it by class name.  "workerBeeFunc" is my delegate called by EnumChildWindows.  Spy++ tells me the navigation Pane window is the child of the second window having a class name "NUIDocumentWindow" (I've left all the WinAPI DLLImport statements out here):

```
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277; // Vertical scroll
private const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3; // Scrolls one page down
static StringBuilder childWindowNames = new StringBuilder();
private int NUIWindowCounter = 0;
private stopIterating as bool = false;

public delegate int EnumChildProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);  //Declare the delegate

public int workerBeeFunc(IntPtr hwndChild, IntPtr Param) //The function the delegate of EnumChildWindows goes to to get the work done.
{
   int a;
   a = WinAPIs.GetWindowText(hwndChild, childWindowNames, 100); //childWindowNames gets cleared on each iteration of this function

   if (childWindowNames.ToString() == "NUIDocumentWindow")
   { 
      NUIWindowCounter++;


      if (NUIWindowCounter == 2)  //The NEXT window is the Navigation Pane
      {
         stopIterating = true;
      }
   return 1;  //Keep iterating
   }

   if (stopIterating == true)
   {
      SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);
      return 0;   //Stop iterating
   }
}
```

Will SendMessage silently fail because of UIPI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Addins run in the same security context as Outlook itself.

There is no requirement for any control to use the WM_VSCROLL message. Do you actually see it in Spy++?

Comment: No, I don't have much familiarity with Spy++ but what I saw on the surface.  Is it able to show the events that are responded to by an application?

Comment: Sure - "Spy | Log Messages" in Spy++.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea. When I tried it, logging shows nothing at all. Not sure why, unless those messages are just dropped. As a followup: is there any message I can send to that Outlook control that it will respond to and that will cause the desired behavior? I looked at using SendInput to send a sequence of down arrow messages, but haven't tried that yet.